# Turn off the SSH Agent

Tags: ssh

How do I turn the SSH Agent off? I'm having troubles with Vagrant and it indicates that I should disable my SSH Agent before continuing, yet I can't find a straight forward answer. How would I do it?

Temporary answers work too. I'm happy with how my environment is setup, it's just this particular situation where I need to verify that disabling the SSH Agent corrects the issue, even if I then turn it back on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

unset the environment variable `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. In `bash`, from where you run the `vagrant` commands, simply:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=""
```

Comment: Any comment for the downvote?

Comment: Any idea on how to do this permanently?

Comment: The other answer sounds like permanent solution. Or you can write this into your `~/.bashrc`. It will practically disable it permanently for all the sessions. (after relogin).

Comment: Works great for me. To disable it for just a single connection (while preserving the agent in the terminal session), I ran a command like this: `SSH_AUTH_SOCK="" ssh user@127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 4):

```
launchctl stop com.openssh.ssh-agent
```

Answer (score 4):

`eval $(ssh-agent -k)` kills the agent in the current terminal.

It runs these commands

```
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 89141 killed;
```